# Check if tab/page is pinned in Safari App Extension

Tags: swift, safari, safari-app-extension

I am writing a [Safari App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions) which gets all open tabs as urls. Later I want to open them.
The problem I am facing is that I cannot find an API for checking if a tab (page) is [pinned](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/pin-frequently-visited-websites-ibrw0495694f/mac).
This leads to the problem that opening all gathered urls also opens all pinned ones, which is not desired.

Is there a way to identify if a tab/page is pinned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a further research I managed to solve this.
To answer the question directly - at the moment there is no API to ask if a tab/page is pinned. But there is a workaround to check this.

There is a discussion [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/62410) and another answer [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123120) which discuss that `getContainingWindow(completionHandler:)` of `SFSafariTab` will return `nil` if the tab is pinned, as technically the pinned tabs belong to all windows, and not a single window.

**Therefore, if tab is pinned, `nil` is returned for containing window.**